# Batch to convert txt file into json file

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have a text file named, `proxy.txt`

which contains,

```
84.15.160.174:4145
178.208.17.195:9999
58.253.154.117:9999
112.87.71.194:9999
```

I found this URL » https://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/
converts the text into json.

Same i like to have in a batch..

expected output in `output.txt`

```
[{"84.15.160.174:4145":"178.208.17.195:9999"},
{"58.253.154.117:9999":"112.87.71.194:9999"}]
```

Comment: No. Am sorry i made a mistake while typing. Now fixed. i need the same output from the input. but, in a json format.

Comment: I.e. you need to combine each line pair into one JSON object. Does you guarantee that the amount of lines is even?

Comment: Yes. But, I can't guarantee the amount of line is even. Anyway no problem if last single ip without pair got deleted. Or its ok with not pair, One line one ip port is also ok. But, main thing it have to be inside it " " So omly i choosen json.

Comment: Does the next format: `[<br>{addresses pair},<br>{addresses pair},<br>,...,{addresses pair},<br>]` is safe for you? Or it is to be strongly like shown one?

Comment: Batch file can not convert text to json. One batch script may solve this specific question but not all. Use C++, Python like programming languages.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Author needs to convert text to text which can be treated as CORRECT json - not more.

Comment: @Akina Yes that's ok for me. If its confusing, just forget about json. Just i like to convert the text in input with " this symbol on its front and back. for example, "84.15.160.174:4145" like this in output for every lines..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [test.bat]

```
@echo off 
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cls
set tmp=
echo [
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%a in (proxy.txt) do (
    IF "!tmp!"=="" (
        SET tmp=%%a
    ) ELSE (
        echo {"!tmp!":"%%a"},
        set tmp=
    )
)
echo {"%tmp%":""}]
```

## [proxy.txt]

```
84.15.160.174:4145
178.208.17.195:9999
58.253.154.117:9999
112.87.71.194:9999
```

## Output:

```
[
{"84.15.160.174:4145":"178.208.17.195:9999"},
{"58.253.154.117:9999":"112.87.71.194:9999"},
{"":""}]
```

## [proxy.txt]

```
84.15.160.174:4145
178.208.17.195:9999
58.253.154.117:9999
112.87.71.194:9999
11.22.33.44:5555
```

## Output:

```
[
{"84.15.160.174:4145":"178.208.17.195:9999"},
{"58.253.154.117:9999":"112.87.71.194:9999"},
{"11.22.33.44:5555":""}]
```

PS. If empty object is not safe for you (when the amount of lines is even) then you may add proper `IF` to the last `echo`. You may also wrap the `FOR` body into `IF` which will skip empty lines in proxy.txt if needed.